# C#.Net case-insensitive string

Tags: c#, .net

Why does C#.Net allow the declaration of the string object to be case-insensitive?

```
String sHello = "Hello";
string sHello = "Hello";
```

Both the lower-case and upper-case S of the word String are acceptable and this seems to be the only object that allows this.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string#7077) for more information.

Comment: Firstly, it is not case-insensitive. You can’t write `STRING` or `strinG` or anything else. Secondly, it is not the only type that has an alias: `object` is an alias for `Object`; `bool` is an alias for `Boolean`; `double` is an alias for `Double`, etc. Incidentally, `void` is also an alias for `Void`, but C# doesn’t let you use `Void`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**`string`** is a language keyword while `System.String` is the type it aliases.

Both compile to exactly the same thing, similarly:

- **`int`** is `System.Int32`
- **`long`** is `System.Int64`
- **`float`** is `System.Single`
- **`double`** is `System.Double`
- **`char`** is `System.Char`
- **`byte`** is `System.Byte`
- **`short`** is `System.Int16`
- **`ushort`** is `System.UInt16`
- **`uint`** is `System.UInt32`
- **`ulong`** is `System.UInt64`

I think in most cases this is about code legibility - all the basic system value types have aliases, I think the lower case `string` might just be for consistency.

Answer (score 6):

Further to the other answers, it's good practice to use keywords if they exist.

E.g. you should use **string** rather than **System.String**.

Answer (score 2):

"String" is the name of the class. "string" is keyword that maps this class.

it's the same like

- Int32 => int
- Decimal => decimal
- Int64 => long

... and so on...

Answer (score 1):

"string" is a C# keyword. it's just an alias for "System.String" - one of the .NET BCL classes.

Answer (score 1):

"string" is just an C# alias for the class "String" in the System-namespace.

Answer (score 0):

string is an alias for System.String.  They are the same thing.

By convention, though, objects of type (System.String) are generally refered to as the alias - e.g.

```
string myString = "Hello";
```

whereas operations on the class use the uppercase version
e.g.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStringVariable);
```

Comment: I don't think the convention is particularly to use the upper case version for operations. I certainly haven't seen that written down. The important thing is to use the BCL version for public names, e.g. ReadSingle instead of ReadFloat.

Comment: says who? never heard of this convention!

Answer (score 0):

I use String and not string,
Int32 instead of int, 
so that my syntax highlighting picks up on a string as a Type and not a keyword. I want keywords to jump out at me.