# What is the difference between uint and System.UInt32?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a difference, or are they just aliases?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, they are aliases. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) the full list.

Comment: I prefer the UInt32 since in some programming languages (C, not C#), the sizes of "int" and "uint" depend on the system you are working on.

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference they are aliasses.

Answer (score 7):

They are aliases but:

```
enum A : uint
{
    // This code compiles
}

enum A : UInt32
{
    // Compile error
}
```

Comment: I didn't know this, can you please explain why it is so?

Comment: I don't know the clear answer =) There's some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813408/c-int-int32-and-enums

Answer (score 6):

`uint` is a C# data type and

`System.UInt32` is a .Net data type(or the data types which CLR has).

The C# data type is translated in to .Net data type when the program is run.
All the other programming languages'(that work in .Net) data types  will be translated into equivalent .Net data types when run. All the data type of the programming languages including C# must adhere to CTS(Common Type System).

Answer (score 4):

Nothing. `uint` is just an alias for `System.UInt32`.

Comment: Don't you mean System.UInt32?

Answer (score 2):

It's just an alias: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88418.aspx