# Why does enum declaration accept short but not Int16

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I want to declare a new enum with non-default underlying type. This works:

```
public enum MyEnum : short
{ A, B, C, }
```

But I don't understand the reason why this doesn't compile:

```
public enum MyEnum : System.Int16
{ A, B, C, }
```

Compiler says

> Type byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int,
>   uint, long, or ulong expected

I understand that short is an alias for Int16 on all .NET versions (32/64 bit flavors included). I don't see why the compiler gives a different meaning to the alias in that particular case.

Any explanation?

Comment: I remember a similar question getting closed yesterday

Comment: I found two almost identical questions using Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774650/enum-members-of-int32-type and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813408/c-int-int32-and-enums.

Comment: I didn't find it despite several minutes spent on reading search results :)

Comment: @Daniel Daranas, sorry I searched using int16 as a keyword... it might explain why I didn't find them

Comment: @Johann Blais, my search was this: http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+enum+type+declaration+int16&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ca:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=dl3&rls=org.mozilla:ca%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=c%23+enum+type+declaration+int16+site:stackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=1&biw=784&bih=532&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&cad=b

Comment: @Daniel Daranas: unfortunately, this search now leads first to this question ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The syntax is correct. C# specification explicitly states that the enum's underlying type must be `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long` or `ulong`.

Read what Microsoft says about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum).

Comment: The link is broken. Please fix

Comment: @Dmitry the link was killed by Microsoft - it worked when I posted it. I fixed it now, but if won't be fixing it every time it breaks.

Answer (score 4):

"...The second example is trying to inherit from a type that derives from System.ValueType, which is strictly prohibited..."

Read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/70b8b7f1-a561-4117-8c78-41880e723da2):

Comment: Lot of discussion for what looks like a small thing :)