# Why can't I base an enum off UInt16?

Tags: c#, .net

Given the code below:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyEnum).BaseType.FullName);
}

enum MyEnum : ushort
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

It outputs System.Enum, which means the colon here has nothing to do with inheritance, and it just specifies the basic type of the enum, am I right?

But if I change my code as follows:

```
enum MyEnum : UInt16
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

I would get a compilation error. Why? Aren't `UInt16` and `ushort` the same?

Comment: Wouldn't have thought to try this, but an interesting observation nonetheless.

Comment: Someone (not the OP) edited this post and changed the last question from "Aren't UInt16 and int the same?".  are you sure the OP didn't really mean what they asked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813408/c-sharp-int-int32-and-enums
or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774650/enum-members-of-int32-type
or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care/62800#62800 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance

Comment: @BradleyUffner I made a mistake. I was planning to ask "Aren't UInt16 and ushort the same?"

Comment: @BradleyUffner: Considering that the two code snippets used `ushort` and `System.UInt16`, it's clear those are the two being compared.

Comment: @CodeCanvas Thanks. I should have noticed that there were questions similar with it asked before.

Comment: Enums can now use UInt16 as the base type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct that reflection doesn't report that an enum inherits the base type, which the specification calls the "underlying type".  You can find it using [`Enum.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype.aspx) instead.

The type named by `ushort` and `System.UInt16` are precisely the same.

However, the syntax of `enum` does not call for a type.  Instead it calls for one of a limited set of keywords, which control the underlying type.  While `System.UInt16` is a valid underlying type, it is not one of the keywords which the C# grammar permits to appear in that location.

Quoting [the grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812.aspx):

> *enum-declaration*:
>
> > *attributes*<sub>opt</sub>   *enum-modifiers*<sub>opt</sub>   **`enum`**   *identifier*   *enum-base*<sub>opt</sub>   *enum-body*   **`;`**<sub>opt</sub>
>
> *enum-base*:
>
> > **`:`**   *integral-type*
>
> *integral-type*:
>
> > **`sbyte`**
> >
> > **`byte`**
> >
> > **`short`**
> >
> > **`ushort`**
> >
> > **`int`**
> >
> > **`uint`**
> >
> > **`long`**
> >
> > **`ulong`**
> >
> > **`char`**

Answer (score 5):

Because the valid types for an enum are explicitly specified to be the integral types (except `char`).

> The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

One *would* expect the `UInt16` to be equivalent to a `ushort` given the documentation for built in types:

> The C# type keywords and their aliases are interchangeable. For example, you can declare an integer variable by using either of the following declarations...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

Edit: I had messed around with this answer a few times not quite grasping the correct answer.  @BenVoight is correct.  The accepted list are the integral types (other than `char`)  The `System.UInt16` is exactly the same type as `ushort`, but it is not an integral type identifier (merely a struct type) as specified by *the grammar*.

Comment: No, it's because the grammar doesn't allow a type identifier to appear there.  The only allowed production is *integral-type*, the choices for which are keywords.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was contradicting myself there :/  Edited/credit given where due.

Answer (score 4):

That's [compiler error CS1008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sab1z73a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and it pretty much provides the answer. The [approved types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for an enum:

> The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int,
>   uint, long, or ulong.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question is answered by others, but no one has addressed the 2nd part yet. **Someone other than the OP has since edited the 2nd question, my answer *may* no longer apply**

`UInt16` and `UInt` are not the same, `UInt16` is an unsigned 16 bit integer, `UInt` is an unsigned 32 bit integer.  They vary quite a bit in their maximum value.

Just for completeness, I'm including the answer to the. first question also:

`The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.`

Answer (score 1):

As for why?

My guess is CLS compliance.