# C#: Is Int16 the same as short?

Tags: c#

If `short` is just the C# syntax for using the `Int16` struct, 
and you can interchange each like this:

```
Int16 x = 10;
//or
short x = 10;
```

then why can you do this:

```
public enum DaysOfWeek : short
{

}
```

but not this:

```
public enum DaysOfWeek : Int16
{

}
```

The error is `Type byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long or ulong expected.`

Comment: The enum grammar doesn't call for a type, it calls for one of a fixed set of keywords.

Comment: The best answer to this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774650/enum-members-of-int32-type

Comment: From http://reinventingthewheel.azurewebsites.net/DotNetFacts.aspx:
"The reason for this is because Int32 is not a keyword, you could create your own class called Int32, but the enum would not be allowed to derive from this since it wouldn't be an integral type."