# Underlying Enum Type of UInt32 Results In Compiler Error

Tags: c#, enums

I know that the recommended underlying type should be an Int32 as it is CLS-compliant, while UInt32 is not, but what I cannot figure out is why this line results in a compiler error:

```
public enum Strength : UInt32
```

and this line does not:

```
public enum Strength : uint
```

I was under the assumption that `uint` is just an alias for `UInt32`, is there something I am missing?  I went through the MSDN documentation, but I could have easily missed something.

Note:  Using VS12, and this error looks like it occurs whenever I use the non-aliased name of an integral type (Int32, int...etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct `uint` is an alias for `UInt32` however the compiler depends on the type to be the alias expected. The same happens with `int` and `Int32`. This is a compiler error from the parser. The parser is expecting specific strings from its internal grammar rules. There are a few other posts about this on Stack Overflow.

Here is another post with more information. [C# int, Int32 and enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813408/c-sharp-int-int32-and-enums)