# Force VS to use System.[Type] in Code Completion

Tags: visual-studio, settings, code-completion

Is it possible to have Visual Studio code completion use the System.[Type] instead of the keyword.

Example:

Autocomplete of `List<String> myList =`  completes as:

```
List<String> myList = new List<string>();
```

whereas, I want:

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>():
```

This isn't the only example, but hopefully shows what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you don't want to use the standard C# keywords for those types?

Comment: @Matti - Personal preference mostly. Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care

Comment: You could try saving your settings and edit the .vssettings file by hand and load them back.  "Rename_Strings" looks somewhat promising, no idea if that's what it does.