# Apparently it's important to use Int32 instead of int when messing with DLLImport stuff?

Tags: c#, int, alias, int32

In C#, when messing with that system DLLImport/(unmanaged?) code stuff, I read somewhere it's important to use Int32 exact type instead of int. Is this true? And can someone please elaborate on why it's important to do this?

Comment: Do you happen to remember where you read it? It would be interesting if you could post the link.

Comment: Related: [62503](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care)

Answer (score 6):

I think it is more likely that you read about using [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx) instead of `int`. As others have said, `int` and `Int32` are equivalent.

It is not really a problem to interchange `int` and `IntPtr` on a 32-bit system as they are the same size (4 bytes). The problem comes when on a 64-bit system - if you use `int` instead of `IntPtr`, it now has the wrong size (4 bytes instead of 8 bytes) and can cause errors.

Comment: Using IntPtr incorrectly can be a problem for the same reason.


If the type you are marshaling is an integer, you should use Int32 (or its alias.) If the type you are marshaling is a pointer, you should use IntPtr. Using IntPtr to marshal an integer is going to create problems since, on 64-bit Windows, an integer is still 32 bits (4 bytes). Similarly, using integer to marshal a pointer will create problems.


Always use the correct managed type for the native type being marshaled and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this is true. `int` is an alias for `Int32`. They mean the exact same thing and will be compiled to the same IL.

A list of aliases can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds%28VS.80%29.aspx).