# Is System.Int32 any slower than using int?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, int or Int32? Should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care)

Couple of questions on System.Int32:

1. Is there any specific technical reason why sizeof(System.Int32) is not allowed?
2. How fast or slow is System.Int32 in comparison to int type?
3. Calling System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf on a variable of type System.Int32 results in 4; how does this work? Would the size of this class be exactly same as that of int internally?

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care

Comment: Calling System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf on a variable of type System.Int32 results in...?

You didn't finish that sentence.

Comment: @diadem: He did, but someone misunderstood and edited the question.

Comment: @mcandre -- this is *definitely* not a duplicate. I am trying to under stand why vanilla sizeof does not work and how despite being a class the size is still maintained as 4.

Comment: Try to avoid asking multiple questions in one posting. You have three questions here, none of which actually have anything to do with each other. The first is a question about language design, the second is a question about performance, and the third is a question about an implementation detail of the marshaller. Reopen these as three separate questions and you'll be much more likely to get all of them answered.

Answer (score 4):

Effectivly there is no difference.

`int == Int32`.

The former is implicitly 32 bits, while Int32 spells it out, similarly Int64 and Int16 (long and short respectivly) do the same.