# Advantages/disadvantages of int and Int32

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What are the advantages/disadvantages of **int** and **Int32**? And Why should we use first instead of second?

Comment: Both are the same ...
[Have a look][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care

Comment: Providing a proper answer for this question requires a time machine.  Once that forwards you into a future where everybody has a 256-bit cpu in their wrist watch.  Whether int is then *still* an alias for Int32 is unanswerable.

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/a/215422/926460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are in fact one and the same -- both declare 32-bit integers, and for the most part their behavior will be identical. The shorthand `int` is just an alias for the `Int32` system type.

From the language specification:

> **4.1.4 Simple Types**
> C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types. The simple types are identified through reserved words, but these reserved words are simply aliases for predefined struct types in the System namespace, as described in the table below.

Here is a list of the simple types and their aliases:

```
Reserved word   Aliased type
sbyte           System.SByte
byte            System.Byte
short           System.Int16
ushort          System.UInt16
int             System.Int32
uint            System.UInt32
long            System.Int64
ulong           System.UInt64
char            System.Char
float           System.Single
double          System.Double
bool            System.Boolean
decimal         System.Decimal
```

There are only a couple instances I can think of where using one over the other would matter. The first is where it's important to know the limitations of the type (e.g. cryptography), but that's only for readability. The other is with an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum : Int32
{
    member1 = 0 //no good
}

public enum MyEnum : int
{
    member1 = 0 //all is well
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `enum` difference (the only place it matters to the compiler).

Answer (score 2):

**There is no any practical advantage or disadvantage**.

The **only** difference is can be that you esplicitly visualize in case of `int32` that you're ddealing with `32 bit` value.

That is.

Comment: I saw Int32 in reflector and it has 5 parent interface and many methods. I think it should affect performance or something. thanks.

Comment: @WaterDance: no, there is no any performance differencies, feel free to use any of them.

Answer (score 1):

`int` is just an alias to `Int32`. So, just use what do you like more.

Answer (score 1):

`int` is an alias for **System**.Int32

If you're not `using System;` you don't have `Int32`.
That's why `int` is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

As stated an int is basically an Int32. But one difference would be that the "using System;" namespace would have to be included while using Int32.