# Wrapper Class in Java vs C#

Tags: c#, java, .net

In case of Java when we write something like

```
Integer i = new Integer(20);
```

In the above case the obj is allocated on the heap

and in case of C#

```
Int32 i = new Int32();
i=10;
```

In this case the object is allocated on the stack

Are these just the difference in implementation wise or there are more differences too?

**Correction:** changed Integer to Int32 for C#

Comment: How you define `Integer` for C#? (there is `System.Int32`/`int`, but no `Integer`)...

Comment: C# doesn't have explicit types representing boxed primitives. It's just an object that could be cast back to the appropriate type. It's nowhere near as complicated as it is in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Integer` in C#, its either [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and both are same. With respect to C# saying "Value types go to stack" is some what not correct. You need to see this article from Eric Lippert:
[The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)

Edit: based on comment:

**Int32 and int are same, the two are synonymous.**

Comment: @Akash, Int32 and int are same, the two are synonymous.

Comment: @Akash: `int` _is_ `System.Int32`, it's merely an alias.

Comment: @Akash, you may also check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care

Answer (score 3):

Many of the reasons you may wish to wrap a primitive in Java don't apply to C# because C# has structs instead of primitives. The following are some of the things structs can be used for that can't be done with prmitives:

- They have methods. Eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx shows the methods available for int32. E.g converting to string is a method call.
- They can be used in Generic data structures. E.G List < int > is perfectly fine.

When they are needed on the heap they can be boxed. This link explains it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx.