# Use "int" or "Int32" while type casting?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, int or Int32? Should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care)

I'm using `GetPosition(this)` when `MouseMoved event` gets triggered so having:

```
Point pt = e.GetPosition(this);
```

As far as I see both following type casts work but which one is recommended and why?

```
int x = (int)pt.X;
int x = (Int32)pt.X;
```

Comment: samething, when its converted to IL int will be int32 so don't worry @amit kohan

Comment: recommended that you use the data type provided by the language. So for C# it would be `int`.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to go with the data type specified in the documentation.  If the `X` and `Y` properties of `Point` are documented as `int`s, then that is what I would use.

Comment: @HansPassant The `X` property I'm pretty sure is a double.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing - they'll even compile to the same IL. (Assuming you haven't got some crazy other `Int32` type somewhere...)

`int` is just an alias for `global::System.Int32`.

(This doesn't just apply to casting - it's almost anywhere that a type name is used.)

Comment: They have different semantics, though, since `Int32` is an ordinary identifier which could stand for any value (like variable or property access) or type (you could have types in other namespaces also called `Int32`). On the other hand `int` is always a (particular) type. One consequence is if you cast the negation (unary minus) of something, it is OK to say **`(int)-pt.X`**. However **`(Int32)-pt.X`** will always be seen as a subtraction (binary minus), even if `Int32` could only be a type with the given names in the given scope. Of course you can fix that with `(Int32)(-pt.X)`.