# Is it possible to create System.Int32 in C#?

Tags: c#, clr

If you get under the hood, value types in C# are treated very specially by compiler/CLR. But types internal to CLR are treated even more specially. Here is what I mean:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
int с = a + b;
a.CompareTo(b);
```

You can hover with your mouse over `int` in Visual Studio and see that actually it is `System.Int32` struct. That's OK. Now you can grab ILDasm and look into what `System.Int32` is: turns over that it is very simple struct with one field of type `int32` (this is `int32` internal to CLR) and there is no overloaded operator for addition.

So, how this `int с = a + b` works then? Again I grab ILDasm and look into IL. Turns out that there is no `System.Int32` in IL code: compiler automatically understands that it should replace it with `int32`. And there is IL instruction `add` that works for couple of `int32` on a stack. What amuses me even more, CLR allows to call instance methods for `System.Int32` on `int32`. Looks like some black magic to me.

So, here goes the pure theoretical question: seems that `System.Int32` is type like any other, could it be created in C# somehow? And if it could, could you do anything useful with it (actual `int32` field is private)?

**Edit:** Ok, to make it a bit more clear: this question have nothing about `int` being alias to `System.Int32`. One can take provided example, replace `int` with `System.Int32` and skip first paragraph after the example. The real question is about possibility to have `valuetype [mscorlib]System.Int32 a` in your IL code instead of just `int32 a`.

Comment: `int a = new int();` is the same as `System.Int32 a = new System.Int32();`. It's just syntactic sugar. Both will be represented internally as `int32`. Even though there are a handful of structs in the CLR that are handled "magically", it's better than some other languages like Java where getting all the extras requires boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, consider the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 5;
        Print(x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Print(object x)
    {
        int y = (int)x;
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
```

in ILDasm:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 x)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloc.0
  IL_0004:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0009:  call       void Test.Program::Print(object)
  IL_000e:  nop
  IL_000f:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
  IL_0014:  pop
  IL_0015:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main

.method private hidebysig static void  Print(object x) cil managed
{
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 y)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  unbox.any  [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0007:  stloc.0
  IL_0008:  ldloc.0
  IL_0009:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_000e:  nop
  IL_000f:  ret
} // end of method Program::Print
```

`[mscorlib]System.Int32` is used for boxing/unboxing only. When the variable is in stack, it's always `int32`.

---

From [Int32 and int](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.devel.dotnet.clr/2003-10/msg00453.html):

It might be helpful to think of System.Int32 as a shadow type for int32.

The following C# code:

```
int x = 0;
x.ToString();
```

Is this in IL:

```
ldc.i4.0
stloc.0
ldloca.s 0
call instance class System.String [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
pop
```

Notice how it's passing an int32 into a seemingly incompatible System.Int32
struct. The engine allows this cause it has been hardwired to recognise
System.Int32 as the shadow type of int32.

Comment: One can move further with boxing example:

    `int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    Object oa = a;
    Object ob = b;
    Int32 с = ((Int32)oa) + ((Int32)ob);`

If you examine IL you'll see:

    `IL_0013: ldloc.2
    IL_0014: unbox.any [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_0019: ldloc.3
    IL_001a: unbox.any [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_001f: add`

So, as `add` works with CLR primitives one can conclude that there is no such thing as "unboxed System.Int32" and `System.Int32` is used only for creating type objects.

Answer (score 1):

`int32` vs `int`(==`System.Int32`)

From [Understanding .NET Primitive Types](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2007/12/20/understanding-net-primitive-types.aspx) :

> int32 is a CLR primitive. Then in FCL, it is represented by
>   System.Int32 struct. The integer value of System.Int32 is persisted on
>   its m_value filed, and a lot of integer-related methods are defined on
>   System.Int32.
>
> In C#, int is just an alias for System.Int32, supported by the C#
>   compiler. So there is no dependency between int and System.Int32

From [IL "The Language of CLR"](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nrsurapaneni/ILtheLangOfCLRbyNRS12222005040956AM/ILtheLangOfCLRbyNRS.aspx):

> All compilers under .NET will generate Intermediate Language no matter
>   what language is used to develop an application. In fact, CLR will not
>   be aware of the language used to develop an application. All language
>   compilers will generate a uniform, common language called Intermediate
>   Language.

So, in C# `System.Int32` is what we have for IL `int32`. I don't know the way to work with IL straight from C# code, and actually don't see any reason for.

There is one: [Tool to allow inline IL in C# / VB.Net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/02/21/377806.aspx)

---

As for `int` vs `System.Int32`:

A post on int and System.Int32 on SO: [C#, int or Int32? Should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care)

In MSDN:

1. [Int32 Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)
2. [int (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

It's all the same:

```
Int32 i = new Int32();
Int32 j = 5;
int x1 = 2;
Int32 x2 = x1;
```

`int` is a so to say *syntactic sugar*...actually it is System.Int32

Besides have a look at C# language specs 4.1.4 Simple types:

> C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types.
>   The simple types are identified through reserved words, but these
>   reserved words are simply aliases for predefined struct types in the
>   System namespace, as described in the table

where

1. short => System.Int16
2. int => System.Int32
3. long => System.Int64

and so on.

Comment: But `int32` and `Int32` are not the same. There is no such thing as `int32` in C#.

Comment: read this: http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2007/12/20/understanding-net-primitive-types.aspx

Comment: Nice article. But it explicitly states that I wrote above: `Int32` and `int32` are not the same (also `int` != `int32`). I'm not arguing about `Int32` and `int` here. The question is about `Int32` and `int32`.

Comment: Did you read the article: "*int32 is a CLR primitive. Then in FCL, it is represented by System.Int32 struct.*"

Comment: Sorry, don't get your point. I do understand that `Int32` is some magical wrapper around `int32`. They are definitely not the same because `int32` is a primitive and `Int32` is full-fledged type defined in mscorlib. There is really a lot of magic going there (see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/6d183671-2f42-4803-ac08-334d19708bc1) for example). But I see no answer to my original question here: is it possible to create `Int32`.

Comment: @iw.kuchin You are at least asking incorrectly. I guess you should ask, whether it is possible to create `int32` not 'Int32'(==System.Int32). And as the answer - no, as in C# you can only use FCL types, while int32 is IL type. Probably there is a way to address IL straight, but I wouldn't even guess what you could need this for.

Comment: @iw.kuchin http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nrsurapaneni/ILtheLangOfCLRbyNRS12222005040956AM/ILtheLangOfCLRbyNRS.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18620/discussion-between-iw-kuchin-and-konstantin-vasilcov)

Comment: And, you can declare your aliases for any type via using keyword.

using MyInteger = System.Int32;

Answer (score 0):

The CLR has a set of primitive types they are defined by the CorElementType enum.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232600.aspx

The add, sub, div, rem, etc opcodes operate on these types.  The JIT will turn these into some fast assembly code.  You cannot define new ones.  You can look at the code it generates using SOS if you are interested.

If you want to emulate the language experience you can use operator overloads in your type.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx