# If Int32 is just an alias for int, how can the Int32 class use an int?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, internals

Been browsing through .NET source code of [.NET Framework Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252), just for fun of it. And found something I don't understand.

There is a *Int32.cs* file with C# code for `Int32` type. And somehow that seems strange to me. How does the C# compiler compile code for `Int32` type?

```
public struct Int32: IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible {
    internal int m_value;

    // ... 
}
```

But isn't this illegal in C#? If `int` is only an *alias for* `Int32`, it should fail to compile with [Error CS0523](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7b625z82.aspx):

> Struct member 'struct2 field' of type 'struct1' causes a cycle in the struct layout.

Is there some magic in the compiler, or am I completely off track?

Comment: review this 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care

Comment: I think the answers so far are missing the true question: "If `Int32` is just an alias for `int`, how can the Int32 class *use* an `int`?"

Comment: There's some good discussion here about the exact same question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/6d183671-2f42-4803-ac08-334d19708bc1/

Comment: Agreed with @Tim. That's a good question, probably the one that should be asked in the title. jure, I think an [edit] is in order.

Comment: Built-in types are magic. They have to be - otherwise it'd be turtles all the way down.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the stated question. (Perhaps it was before some edits, but it is not now.)

Comment: However, the answer to your question is extremely short. Is there a special case in the compiler to allow for the fact that `System.Int32` has a field of type `System.Int32`, which would normally be an error?  Obviously: **yes**. The question practically answers itself; there would normally be an error, there is not an error for the extremely special case of int, therefore there must be a special case in the compiler. And there is.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> isn't this illegal in C#? If "int" is only alias for "Int32" it should fail to compile with error CS0523. Is there some magic in the compiler?

Yes; the error is deliberately suppressed in the compiler. The cycle checker is skipped entirely if the type in question is a built-in type.

Normally this sort of thing is illegal:

```
struct S { S s; int i; }
```

In that case the size of S is undefined because whatever the size of S is, it must be equal to itself plus the size of an int. There is no such size.

```
struct S { S s; }
```

In that case we have no information from which to deduce the size of S.

```
struct Int32 { Int32 i; }
```

But in this case the compiler knows ahead of time that `System.Int32` is four bytes because it is a very special type.

Incidentally, the details of how the C# compiler (and, for that matter, the CLR) determines when a set of struct types is cyclic is extremely interesting. I'll try to write a blog article about that at some point.

Comment: Int32 was the very first file I opened when .NET source download was complete. And then the first line shocked me. There’s a line of code in .NET source that shouldn’t be there. After few moments of self-doubt, I came to the conclusion, what you are looking at is code for Int struct, it's like singularity, standard laws of physics don't apply here.. so I closed the file : )
Anyway, looking forward to your blog post, always pleasure to read them.

Comment: @jure: It's more like an electron than a singularity. What are the contents of an electron? One electron!

Comment: I thought the contents of an electron were virtual photons and virtual electron-positron pairs. (Similarly, an Int32 should be defined as `struct Int32 { byte byte1; byte byte2; byte byte3; byte byte4; }`

Comment: Wheres my positron so i can cast int to void!

Comment: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto, Size = 4)] struct S { S s; }` would have information to deduce the size of S. But it doesn't feel very useful without special language and compiler support.

Comment: @jure - "... so I closed the file" made me laugh :)

Comment: Mind blown, so Int32 Structure is a structure containing an Int32 type. Cool Microsoft! This, almost doesn't look as a inspector gadget code.

Comment: Mr @EricLippert have you written your the article on your blog that you've mentioned? If so, could you share its link?

Answer (score 13):

`int` is an alias for `Int32`, but the `Int32` struct you are looking at is simply metadata, it is not a real object.  The `int m_value` declaration is possibly there only to give the struct the appropriate size, because it is never actually referenced anywhere else (which is why it is allowed to be there).

So, in other words, the compiler kind of saves this from being a problem.  There is a discussion on the topic [in the MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/6d183671-2f42-4803-ac08-334d19708bc1/).

From the discussion, here is a quote from the chosen answer that helps to try to determine how the declaration is possible:

> while it is true that the type contains an integer m_value field - the
>   field is never referenced. In every supporting method (CompareTo,
>   ToString, etc), "this" is used instead. It is possible that the
>   m_value fields only exist to force the structures to have the
>   appropriate size.
>
> I suspect that when the compiler sees "int", it translates it into "a
>   reference to System.Int32 in mscorlib.dll, to be resolved later", and
>   since it's building mscorlib.dll, it does end up with a cyclical
>   reference (but not one that can ever cause problems, because m_value
>   is never used). If this assumption is correct, then this trick would
>   only work for special compiler types.

Reading further, it can be determined that the struct is simply metadata, and not a real object, so it is not bound by the same recursive definiton restraints.

Comment: I guess if the m_value was declared as Int32 the compile would faile. Interesting discussion on MSDN. At the end, this really doesent matter, but that value types have some strange source code :)

Comment: `System.Int32` is not a class, it's a struct.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that m_value is used in the source code, quite a bit actually. However the compiler's IL emitter has a special rule that  replaces any use of the recursive in a recursive valuetype with a use of the parent object instead. Of course the CLR will refuse not load such a recursive valuetype, except for the built-in ones.