# Why does `Int32` use `int` in its source code?

Tags: c#, int32, reference-source

Why does `Int32` use `int` in its [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,e684b180141a1959,references)? Doesn't `Int32` equal `int` in C#? So what is the original source code for `int`? I'm confused..

```
[Serializable]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
#if GENERICS_WORK
    public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
        , IComparable<Int32>, IEquatable<Int32>
///     , IArithmetic<Int32>
#else
    public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
#endif
    {
        internal int m_value; // Here????

        public const int MaxValue = 0x7fffffff;
        public const int MinValue = unchecked((int)0x80000000);

        ...
    }
```

there is the same issue between `Boolean` and `bool` too.

Comment: Int32 is `struct`.It containd methods and stuffs for manipulating int, int is system defined datatype.

Comment: That *is* the original source code for `int`. Some of the actual inner workings is part of the compiler and of the runtime, but insofar as there is source code, that is the source code.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113850/if-int32-is-just-an-alias-for-int-how-can-the-int32-class-use-an-int Only related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018281/regarding-primitive-data-types-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't have to use int?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Definitely duplicate. Nice find. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int`, `bool` etc are simply aliases for builtin types like `Int32` and `Boolean` respectively. They are shorthand, so it makes sense to use them. even in their own definitions.

The aliases are built into the compiler, so there is no "chicken and egg" situation of `Int32` having to be compiled before `int` is accessible. There is no "original source code" for `int`. The "source" is for `Int32` and is shared between functionality built into the CLR (for handling the primitives) and the framework (for defining functionality for manipulating those primitives). As [this answer to a duplicate question explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16155216/7122), the source for `Int32` isn't a valid definition of the type itself; that's built into the CLR. As such, the compiler has to fudge the normally illegal use of `int` within that file in order to allow the `Int32` type to have functionality.

Comment: So Int32 "includes" itself "recursively"?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @hvd, I think you are confused. Perhaps though you'd care to explain why it doesn't answer the question and maybe even answer the question yourself "correctly"?

Comment: @codroipo, no `int` is a compiler keyword alias for `System.Int32`.

Comment: @DavidArno You made significant edits to your answer after I posted my comment (as can be verified from the comment time and edit times). You do answer the question now. Not as well as Eric Lippert in the linked question, but it's far better than before.

Comment: @hvd, then I look forward to you - and all the other downvoters - removing your -1 :)

Comment: In general, don't count on that happening, it's perfectly reasonable when people downvoting a bad answer no longer even see it after your edits, because they've moved on to other questions. But here, sure, okay. :)

Comment: What's confusing when looking at the source code for an `int` is that we're not really looking at the source code for an `int`. We're looking at the extensions that are added to the primitive `int` type, which in C# doesn't exist. The primitive part of an `int` is handled internally. Maybe your answer should focus on that if you want it to be useful (I haven't downvoted you but I don't think your answer is helpful at the moment).

Comment: @Alex, fair point. As the question has been closed though, I'll just leave it as-is.