# Implementation of Int32

Tags: c#

`int` is an alias for `Int32` and is also defined as a keyword in the C# language specification.

The [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs) has this code:

```
[Serializable]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
#if GENERICS_WORK
    public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
        , IComparable<Int32>, IEquatable<Int32>
///     , IArithmetic<Int32>
#else
    public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
#endif
    {
        internal int m_value;

        public const int MaxValue = 0x7fffffff;
        public const int MinValue = unchecked((int)0x80000000);
```

`Int32` encapsulates an `int`. Can somebody explain why the alias is used internally for the alias' definition?  This is the same as long pointing to `Int64` and then `Int64` declaring a `long` variable. I suppose it's the compilers prerogative to do what it pleases and `int` always means 32 bit memory location and this is just a way of adding methods but it is bugging me.

Comment: Remember that what your decompiler generates isn't the same as the code that was originally written. The name of the struct is `Int32`, so that won't change when decompiled, but the decompiler will choose inbuilt types (`Int32` vs `int` or `String` vs `string`) according to its own logic, not the original dev's. (The question of how an `int` can contain an `int` is answered elsewhere; I'm only referring here to the discrepancy between the type name in the decompiled code.)

Comment: @Dirk thanks, I was trying to find the same question. You won.

Comment: Built-in types are magic and they have to be, otherwise it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @Dan I've replaced the decompiled code with the official code and it's the same.

Comment: You are correct int always refer to the 32 bit memory, and int is an alias for System.Int32 struct, check out the following links for more information:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/csharp/PQEO291212-Difference-between-int,-Int16,-Int32-and-Int64.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88418.aspx

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care

Comment: Yes this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113850/if-int32-is-just-an-alias-for-int-how-can-the-int32-class-use-an-int answers the question admirably