# Using <see cref=""/> with an optional and nullable parameter in XML documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation, nullable, optional-parameters

While writing the XML documentation for my program I have run into a problem documenting this method:

```
internal void MethodB(int i, DateTime? date = null);
```

The problem I am having is specfic to the `date` parameter. As you can see, it is **optional** as well as **nullable**. Here is how I tried to document this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method uses <see cref="MethodB(Int32, System.DateTime)"/> internally
/// todo some stuff.
/// </summary>
```

Specifically, I am getting a compiler warning that indicates that the value of [cref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134.aspx) could not be resolved.

How can I fix my XML documentation comment so that it will compile without this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try indicating that the `System.DateTime` parameter is nullable:

```cs
using System;

/// <summary>
/// This method uses <see cref="MethodB(Int32, DateTime?)"/>
/// internally to do some stuff...
/// </summary>
```

**Edit:** And as the OP @WiiMaxx later discovered, there is an alternative syntax:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This method uses <see cref="MethodB(Int32, Nullable{DateTime})"/>
/// internally to do some stuff...
/// </summary>
```

Note also that the language-specific type `int` can be used as an alternative to the system type `Int32` (and some would argue that `int` is preferable):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This method uses <see cref="MethodB(int, DateTime?)"/>
/// internally to do some stuff...
/// </summary>
```

**See:** [int or Int32? Should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62503/1497596) and [What's the difference between String and string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7074/1497596).

Finally, regardless whether the XML documentation comment includes `Int32` or `int`, `Int32` will appear in the generated documentation (which is not programming language-specific).

Comment: Anything that uses a type (e.g. `Nullable{DateTime}`) will not display as `Nullable<DateTime>` but as `Nullable<T>` in the comment browser.