# Why do primitive data types work without including the System namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, primitive

I read that all primitives fall under the `System` namespace.  If I comment out `using System` I would expect there to be a build error in my program,   however it is running successfully.  Why is this?

[image: Attached the snap of my sample program.]

Comment: _Even_ if you delete all namespaces, it will work :) Just a hint, if you say `Int32` instead of `int`, it won't work.

Comment: `int` is an *alias* for `System.Int32` (which you would not be able to use)

Comment: @AlexK.I am able to use int even though I comment using System;

Comment: @RajeshPawde Yes because `int` is _already_ `System.Int32`. It doesn't need _any_ namespace because it has _already_. Think about like this; you are using `Console.WriteLine` with `using System`, right? What if you have `System.Console.WriteLine`, do you need `using System` for that? No, because it has _already_. This is the same as for `System.Int32` which is aliased by `int`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#, int or Int32? Should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care)

Comment: @UweKeim IMO they are related, but asking different questions fundamentally; this question also gets into the topic of using fully qualified types, without the using directive

Comment: @iliketocode Agree with you both the questions are different.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's because `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`, and since the "Int32" is already prefixed with its namespace (ie. "fully qualified"), the syntax is legal without having to specify `using System;` at the top of your code.

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx) snippet below describes this concept-

> Most C# applications begin with a section of using directives. This section lists the namespaces that the application will be using
>   frequently, and saves the programmer from specifying a fully qualified
>   name every time that a method that is contained within is used. For
>   example, by including the line:
>
> ```
> using System;
> ```
>
> At the start of a program, the programmer can use the code:
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
> ```
>
> Instead of:
>
> ```
> System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
> ```

`System.Int32` (aka "int") would be the latter.  Here is an example of this in code -

```
//using System;

namespace Ns
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Int32 i = 2;    //OK, since we explicitly specify the System namespace
            int j = 2;             //alias for System.Int32, so this is OK too
            Int32 k = 2;           //Error, because we commented out "using System"
        }
    }
}
```

Since line 11 is not fully qualified / aliasing a fully qualified type, `using System;` would need to be uncommented for the error to go away.

Additional references-

- *[C#, int or Int32? Should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503)*
- *[Built-In Types Table (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx)*
  (Lists all the built-in types, and their .NET framework equivalents)

Comment: Either my monitor's gamma is out or your vision is that of a bee ;)  (color scheme)

Comment: Yes.. I usually code on a black background.  Just switched the colors to white, this should be a little better.

Comment: Hehe that's better.  I use the dark scheme too it was just _dark blue_ does crazy stuff to my eyes ;)

Answer (score 8):

As was mention before `int` is an alias of `System.Int32` type. The alias of primitive types *are implicitly known* by the C# language. Here is the list:

```
object:  System.Object
string:  System.String
bool:    System.Boolean
byte:    System.Byte
sbyte:   System.SByte
short:   System.Int16
ushort:  System.UInt16
int:     System.Int32
uint:    System.UInt32
long:    System.Int64
ulong:   System.UInt64
float:   System.Single
double:  System.Double
decimal: System.Decimal
char:    System.Char
```

So, for these aliases, also known as *simple types*, you don't need to specify any namespace.

Comment: In other words, "compiler magic".  ++ the most on topic answer on this Q.

Answer (score 4):

When you use int, you are basically putting in System.Int32. Since this is the fully qualified type name, you don't actually need `using System;`

Your program would work if you did

```
 System.Int32 num = 0;
```

even without the `using`

Comment: No this will raise the compile error if we are not using the using System;

Comment: @RajeshPawde no it won't. `System.Int32` is fully qualified and doesn't need a `using System;`