# Newtonsoft Json Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

When performing an AJAX request I am getting the following error:

> Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path '[5].tabID', line 1, position 331.

The error occurs on the second line of my `processRequest (...)`

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) { 
    string strJson = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    List<ElementToUpdate> elements = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ElementToUpdate>>(strJson);

    // (...)
}
```

The debugger says that this the content of `strJson`:

```
[{
    "bmk": "132M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "motor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "158M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "motor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "194M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "motor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "198M1",
    "state": "on",
    "type": "motor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "202M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "motor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "test-m",
    "state": "on",
    "type": "motor",
    "tabID": null
}, {
    "bmk": "158M1-2",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "motor",
    "tabID": 2
}, {
    "bmk": "100M1",
    "state": "on_right",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "152M1",
    "state": "on",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "192M1",
    "state": "on_left",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "196M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "2000M1",
    "state": "on_left",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "74M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "76M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "80M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "82M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "86M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "90M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "94M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "95M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "96M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "screwconveyor",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "102Y1",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "104Y1",
    "state": "open",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "112Y2",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "114Y2",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "120Y1",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "122Y1",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "128Y2",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "146Y1_2",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "148Y2",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "156Y1",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "180Y1",
    "state": "open",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "182Y1",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "184Y1",
    "state": "open",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "206Y1",
    "state": "open",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "208Y1",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "72Y2",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "78Y2",
    "state": "open",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "84Y2",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "88Y2",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "92Y2",
    "state": "closed",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "95_1Y1",
    "state": "blocked",
    "type": "ventile",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "17H1",
    "state": "on",
    "type": "lamp",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "l1",
    "state": "on",
    "type": "lamp",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "17H1-2",
    "state": "on",
    "type": "lamp",
    "tabID": 2
}, {
    "bmk": "106M1",
    "state": "on",
    "type": "elevator",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "154M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "elevator",
    "tabID": 8
}, {
    "bmk": "164M1",
    "state": "off",
    "type": "rotaryvalve",
    "tabID": 8
}]
```

The class `ElementToUpdate` is

```
public class ElementToUpdate
{
public ElementType type;
public String bmk;
public string state;
public int tabID;

public ElementToUpdate()
{
}

public ElementToUpdate(ElementType type, String bmk, string state, int tabID)
{
    this.type = type;
    this.bmk = bmk;
    this.state = state;
    this.tabID = tabID;
}
}
```

So my question is: How to resolve this issue? If I understand the error message correctly, then it says that `tabID` of the 5th json object in the serialized array is `null`. But as you can see it isn't. Moreover `ElementToUpdate.tabID` isn't an `Int32` but an `int`. Did I miss something?

**The solution**

In fact, my JSON string contained an element whose `tabID` was `null`. I somehow overlooked this because firstly my JSON string wasn't formatted when I checked and secondly because [5] means "6th element of the array" (which I claimed to know actually).

Comment: `int` = `Int32`. Just in case... [C#, int or Int32? Should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care)

Comment: @MelanciaUK That's what I thought, too. But the error message made me unsure...

Comment: I edited the question to expand the JSON string, so it makes it easier to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Make your tabID nullable:

```
public int? tabID;
```

Value `null` could not be deserialized to integer. 
That's your 6-th part of json (or 5-th starting with 0):

```
{\"bmk\":\"test-m\",\"state\":\"on\",\"type\":\"motor\",\"tabID\":null}
```

You could see, that tabID is null there.

Comment: Obviously in none of the objects I am passing as JSON array `tabID` is null.

Comment: @elementzero23  One of tabID's in your JSON is null, either it was null by serialization, or your serialization was wrong.

Comment: Thank you for keeping the answer as is, though. I did not know these kind of things were possible.

Comment: Having to make all of my viewmodel's properties nullable to avoid this issue seems like the wrong way to go about this.

Comment: changing model definitions is not always an option

Comment: Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication. Overlooking simply. +1

Answer (score 40):

Depending on your use case, you may also want to consider having the [JSON Serializer ignore nulls](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm)

Example:

```
Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.Name = "Bad Boys III";
movie.Description = "It's no Bad Boys";

string included = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { });

// {
//   "Name": "Bad Boys III",
//   "Description": "It's no Bad Boys",
//   "Classification": null,
//   "Studio": null,
//   "ReleaseDate": null,
//   "ReleaseCountries": null
// }

string ignored = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

// {
//   "Name": "Bad Boys III",
//   "Description": "It's no Bad Boys"
// }
```

Comment: var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

Comment: This is the best answer.  changing the model property to nullable is not always an option

Comment: I agree with @LastTribunal, tried so many times (11 tests) except for the settings from paulschoeder

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, Because if we start changing the data type to nullable in real time, there are possible to change n number of places. Atleast in my case I was in need to change 50+places and we need to type case everywhere where already implemented using not nullable. So this is more appropriate solution to me,

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was problem with constructor definition. I had

```
public int? tabID { get; }

public Temp(int tabID)
{
   this.tabID = tabID;
}
```

I had to fix the constructor definition to

```
public Temp(int? tabID)...
```