# How to parse decimal in C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm using C#, UWP and Newtonsoft.Json library to parse text to json.

The data I'm trying to parse is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 9,
        "displayNo": 1,
        "ygnGoldPrice": 1111111.00,
        "worldGoldPrice": 33333.00,
        "usDollars": 1640.00,
        "differenceGoldPrice": 12000.00,
        "updatedDate": "2021-04-23T14:59:11Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "displayNo": 2,
        "ygnGoldPrice": 12345.00,
        "worldGoldPrice": 1222.00,
        "usDollars": null,
        "differenceGoldPrice": 1222.00,
        "updatedDate": "2021-04-23T15:01:23Z"
    }
]
```

As you can see, some of the fields have decimal point `.00` and I'm trying to parse them with the following model.

```
class GoldPrice
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int displayNo { get; set; }
    public decimal ygnGoldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal worldGoldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal usDollars { get; set; }
    public decimal differenceGoldPrice { get; set; }
    public string updatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The method that parses

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> GetAll<T>(ObservableCollection<T> list, string path = "")
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    Uri requestUri = new Uri(baseUri + path);

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();

    string httpResponseBody;
    try
    {
         httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
         httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
         httpResponseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         Debug.WriteLine(httpResponseBody); // The data is printed out. OK.

         return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<T>>(httpResponseBody);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         httpResponseBody = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message;
         return null;
     }
 }
```

I'm getting the following error in the line `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject...` saying that
`Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll`.

Comment: You have a null value for us Dollars, but the property is not nullable

Comment: Property updateDate can also be of type DateTime

Comment: Struggling for about 3 hours straight, I got it. It is because of null. How can I declare nullable in my model?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: When you do get it all parsed, and you're wondering why your decimals "lose" their 00, you should appreciate that 1.00 and 1 are the same thing; if you want it to look different it's something you do when you output it, not when you work with it in c#

Comment: `public decimal? usDollars { get; set; }`, note the `?`

Comment: when you get it working, feel free to post an answer to your own question..

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Newtonsoft Json Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41873274/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the data I'm trying to parse has `null`, as you can see in the question.

Therefore, I have to change my model like below, which is capable of accepting `null` and it works.

```
class GoldPrice
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int displayNo { get; set; }
    public decimal? ygnGoldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? worldGoldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? usDollars { get; set; }
    public decimal? differenceGoldPrice { get; set; }
    public string updatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Other alternatives:

1. Use property attribute

   ```
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public decimal usDollars { get; set; }
   ```
2. Specifiy null value handling options for the JsonSerializer

   ```
   var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
          NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
   };

   List<GoldPrice> goldPrices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GoldPrice>>(json, serializerSettings);
   ```