# C# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject giving Null Value Exception even though I have NullValueHandling set to Ignore

Tags: c#, json.net

My data looks like this, except there are 1000s of entities, not just 2.

```json
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "James",
        "last_updated": "2021-04-26",
        "incomplete": true,
        "valid": true,
        "start_date": "2007-03-20",
        "items": 51,
        "current": 1,
        "hitpoints": 52
    }
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Peter",
        "last_updated": "2021-04-25",
        "incomplete": true,
        "members": true,
        "start_date": "2009-06-13",
        "items": 51,
        "current": 1,
        "hitpoints": 52
    }
}
```

My code is like this:

```cs
try
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
    };
    var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Entry>>(json, settings);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); 
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path '455.hitpoints', line 1, position 1597602. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Null object cannot be converted to a value type.
> at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)

I have tried many different ways of doing this. Even put this above hitpoints in the declaration of the Entry class:

```cs
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

Here is the class:

```cs
public class Entry
{
    public Entry(int id_p, string name_p, string last_updated_p, bool incomplete_p, bool valid_p, string start_date_p, int items_p, int size_p, int hitpoints_p)
    {
        id = id_p;
        name = name_p;
        last_updated = last_updated_p;
        incomplete = incomplete_p;
        valid = valid_p;
        start_date = start_date_p;
        items = items_p;
        size = size_p;
        hitpoints = hitpoints_p;
    }
    
    public int  id                      { get; set; }
    public string   name                { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string   last_updated        { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public bool     incomplete          { get; set; }
    public bool     valid               { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string   start_date          { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int  items                   { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int  current                 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int  hitpoints               { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
}
```

Still doing the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: How is `Entry` class defined?

Comment: Also, maybe it's pasting mistake, but your `[JsonProperty(...)]` should be before the property it relates to, not after. You have one "hanging" at the end.

Comment: @Nenad correct, IMHO user should use `JsonSerializerSettings` along with the `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` and get rid of the `[JsonProperty...]` altogether.

Comment: The fact that `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` isn't working seems to be related to the fact that your `Entry` class has a **parameterized constructor**.  Adding a default constructor solves the problem, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/AwIn0U.  Kind of odd, and feels like a bug with Json.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you did not provide class `Entry`, error says that your `Hitpoint` property is `int`, meaning, you cannot assign `null` value to it. You have to define `Hitpoint` as `int?`.

```cs
class Entry
{
    //...
    public int? Hitpoint {get; set; }

}
```

Update:

Only `string` is already `Nullable` type in the `Entry` class you provided. For all `bool` and `int` properties that you want to be "optional", you should change type definition to `bool?` and `int?`.

Comment: I will try that. Never saw that before on any answers or posts regarding null entries. Thanks!

Comment: @TBowman - "convert your value type to nullable" is the accepted answer to [Newtonsoft Json Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41873274/3744182).  What makes your question different is that `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`, which is given as the alternate answer to the same question, is not working in your case.

Comment: @dbc Yes, I see that answer now. Strange how it did not come up in the long list of suggestions when I was framing my question. I actually had the title and my partially written question open for a good 30 minutes while I searched all of the suggested links that had the right keywords. That question and answer would have been a smart suggestion to give me.