# .NET Core API - Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Boolean'

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Recently we have migrated our project from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.1.

Suppose we have a property defined as `bool`, it's not accepting values as null and getting the following error when we try to call API from UI

> Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Boolean'

Tried adding this in start up to fix the issue

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o =>
        {
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
        });
```

Comment: `it's not accepting values as null` it never did. It was never possible to store a `null` in a variable or property that expected a value type like `bool` or `int`. That's why nullable types were introduced. You can only store a `null` if the property is a `bool?`

Comment: The code you posted doesn't try to set any `bool` properties though. Those properties expect `JsonNamingPolicy ` classes and *do* accept nulls. Post the code that actually caused the compilation error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It was not in the case of .NET framework earlier we used.

Comment: Wasn't the case for which code? What you posted works. There are no booleans involved. Where did you get that error? Googling for this shows it's a JSON.NET error which is *not* used by .NET Core 3.1. Did you get the error trying to deserialize a JSON string? What is the json string, what is the target object? Post the relevant code, the JSON text and the *full exception text*, not just parts of it. You can get the full text with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: Nullable types weren't introduced by .NET Core though, they exist for *several* years. And the error message you posted would occur in .NET Old too, [as this possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873274/newtonsoft-json-error-converting-value-null-to-type-system-int32) shows. Somehow, you have a `null` value in your JSON. The property that receives it must be `bool?`, not `bool`. Perhaps you modified the null handling behavior of JSON.NET ?

Comment: Are you trying to use default values when they're missing from the JSON string? What was your default value policy in .NET Framework? You may be able to do the same simply by setting the property's default value, eg `public bool MyFlag {get;set;} = false;`

Comment: Null handling is controlled by the [IngoreNullValues](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.ignorenullvalues?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_IgnoreNullValues) and [DefaultIgnoreCondition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.defaultignorecondition?view=net-5.0). These can be used to [ignore properties with null or default values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-5-0#ignore-all-null-value-properties)

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the start up and it worked for me. Thanks everyone for your suggestions

```
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.UseMemberCasing();
//This will help us in accepting null  values to other properties types
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
```