# int not what I try and assign it

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and having an issue understanding why my highNumber value is being displayed as 56 when running my code snippet.

//Write a program and ask the user to enter a series of numbers separated by comma. Find the maximum of the numbers 
            //and display it on the console. For example, if the user enters “5, 3, 8, 1, 4", the program should display 8

```
int highNumber = 0;

Console.Write("Enter a series of numbers separated by comma: ");
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

for (var i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(userInput[i]) == true)
    {
        if (userInput[i] > highNumber)
        {
            highNumber =  Convert.ToInt32(userInput[i]);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("The largest number is {0}", Convert.ToInt32(highNumber));
```

Comment: Fyi, `Convert.ToInt32(highNumber)` is useless because it's already an `int`

Comment: `if (char.IsNumber(userInput[i]) == true)` is also reduntant. use `if ( char.IsNumber(userInput[i]) )` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LordWilmore`s answer is somehow correct if you dont use numbers greater than 10 but you can simplify and make it more accurate as below:

```
int highNumber = 0;
int valueTemp;
Console.Write("Enter a series of numbers separated by comma: ");
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
string[] array = userInput.Split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (int.TryParse(array[i], out valueTemp))
    {
        if (valueTemp > highNumber)
        {
            highNumber =  valueTemp;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("The largest number is {0}", highNumber);
```

or using [Max()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max(v=vs.110).aspx) function if you have knowledge about the `List<>` in c#:

```
int valueTemp;
Console.Write("Enter a series of numbers separated by comma: ");
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
string[] array = userInput.Split(',');
List<int> intList = new List<int>();

for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (int.TryParse(array[i], out valueTemp))
    {
        intList.Add(valueTemp);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("The largest number is {0}", intList.Max());
```

This is a more accurate example because if put `3,33,4` in your example it will fail since you get each character and not values separated by comma. In my case I split them into pieces accordingly and then continue to test them appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. Looks like turning it into an array was what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

You've entered the ASCII character '8', which has the numeric value 56.

If it's a single digit character then convert it with this

```
int val = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(userInput[i]);
```

If it's a numeric string then convert it in one call with this

```
int val;
bool success = Int32.TryParse(userInput, out val);
```

or

```
int val = System.Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
```

Comment: I know, sorry, I accidentally closed it when switching tabs.  I've updated the answer now

Comment: Note that this only works for single digit values. It breaks if the input is `"128,12,5"`.

Comment: Worth adding the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I recommend against using `Int32` and in favour of `int`, as highlighted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62738/501011)

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine();` returns a `string`. When you use the indexer (`[i]`) on the string you get individual characters, not strings or numbers.  What you want is to [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) the string by the commas, then use `TryParse` to ensure that each string is a number:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
string[] parts = userInput.Split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(parts[i], out number))
    {
        if (number > highNumber)
        {
            highNumber = number;
        }
    }
}
```