# Call external dll import method using int / short instead of Int32 / Int16

Tags: c#, types, parameters, dllimport, extern

I just wondered if it is safe to change the datatypes of a dll import method parameters from "Int32" to "int" or "Int16" to "short". I know that it should be the same compilerwise, but I'm insecure if the imported method is still recognized.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/should-i-use-int-or-int32), they are kind-of-alias.

Comment: The underlying type of `int` is `System.Int32` and the underlying type for `short` is `System.Int16`, so yes, it should work. But why not just test it?

Comment: Because some hardware is needed for the 3rd party dll, which I don't have at the moment. I'm just refactoring the code :) It will be tested aftwerwards but I want to avoid a return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these types are interchangeable.