# String vs string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, string, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

In C# the string keyword (highlighted in Visual Studio as a data type) is just a shortcut to the String class right?

In that case, it would be the same to use either while coding from the semantic point of view. However, is it the same from the performance point of view? I mean, when the mapping is performed: during compilation (I guess so), during compilation or during JIT compilation in execution?

Or maybe this is all wrong: string and String are not the same thing in C# so there are some situations where they cannot be interchanged