# In C# what is the difference between the upper and lower case String/string?

Tags: c#, string, difference

Newbie here, in C# what is the difference between the upper and lower case String/string?

Comment: There is another thread in SO about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c

Answer (score 35):

String uses a few more pixels than string. So, in a dark room, it will cast a bit more light, if your code is going to be read with light-on-dark fonts.  Deciding on which to use can be tricky - it depends on the price of lighting pixels, and whether your readership wants to cast more light or less.  But c# gives you the choice, which is why it is all-around the best language.

Comment: I lol'ed and had to explain why to a coworker...

Comment: I am a better programmer for knowing the "Correct" answer now. Thank you! :)

Comment: In the good old times, most stuff was even completely case-insensitive. WRITING ALL IN UPPERCASE GAVE A LOT OF GREEN LIGHT ON A BLACK CRT-TUBE. 
But in these dark days, we write black on white and the situation has per(re)versed. LOL-good answer.

Comment: saves toner when printing too

Comment: or wastes it if you prefer String. your choice...

Answer (score 16):

Nothing - both refer to `System.String`.

Answer (score 7):

"String" is the underlying CLR data type (class) while "string" is the C# alias (keyword) for String. They are synonomous. Some people prefer using String when calling static methods like String.Format() rather than string.Format() but they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

String is short version of System.String,  the common type system (CTS) Type used by all .Net languages.  string is the C# abbreviation for the same thing...

like

- System.Int32 and int
- System.Int16 and short,

etc.

Answer (score 1):

An object of type "String" in C# is an object of type "System.String", and it's bound that way by the compiler if you use a "using System" directive, like so:
using System;
...
String s = "Hi";
Console.WriteLine(s);
If you were to remove the "using System" statement, I'd have to write the code more explicitly, like so:
System.String s = "Hi";
System.Console.WriteLine(s);
On the other hand, if you use the "string" type in C#, you could skip the "using System" directive and the namespace prefix:
string s = "Hi";
System.Console.WriteLine(s);
The reason that this works and the reason that "object", "int", etc in C# all work is because they're language-specific aliases to underlying .NET Framework types. Most languages have their own aliases that serve as a short-cut and a bridge to the .NET types that existing programmers in those languages understand.

Answer (score 0):

no difference.
string is just synonym of String.

Answer (score 0):

string is an alias for String in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

String is type coming from .NET core (CLR).

string is C# type, that is translated to String in compiled IL.

Language types are translated to CLR types.