# Datatype String vs string in C#

Tags: c#

When to use "String" and when to go for "string" data type in C# ?

What is the difference between them?

Thanks.

---

Duplicate:  [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

Comment: Duplicate, and "nothing at all, except you don't need to qualify `string` with `System.`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. string is an alias of String. The same goes for int and Int32 etc.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. Choose one notation and stick to it.