# C# native data types vs .NET CTS types

Tags: c#, types

While coding we can use C# native data types as well as .NET CTS types. I am curious to know which data type should I use while declaring any variable. I found somewhere that we should use c# native datatype while I believe we should use CTS Type as in IL every data type is going to be in converted in respective CTS type. But I am not sure still which I should use?
Let me know your views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# native types are compiled to EXACTLY the same IL code as their System.* counterparts.

So

```
int x = 1;
```

is exactly the same as:

```
Int32 x = 1;
```

See this question for the complete picture:

[C#, int or Int32? Should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care)

Comment: so should we use .NET CTS types as it will use less time to convert? But then why c# native should be used is suggested?

Comment: I would never use the CTS types in my code. I don't see any reason for doing that. The language provides native datatypes for a reason. And your code looks cleaner if you use native type names.

Comment: but let if I am working in c# and using c++ file, in c++ if I use int that will be int16 but in c#  it will be int32, won't I get some trouble in there?

Comment: int Visual C++, "int" is also Int32

Comment: OK, I found one exception then and that is long. VC++ this is same as Int32 while in c# it is Int64. But the intention is not that, there may be some other conflict too or not?

Answer (score 1):

The makers of the .NET framework recommend using the native C# types in the .NET Framework Design Guidelines book.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet outlines a few pros and cons in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c/215422#215422).