# Is there any difference between String and string in C# like int and Integer in Java?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

I understand there is a difference between Integer and int in Java,

Similarly I realised that String and string kinda works in C# too, is there any differences in these 2? Datatype vs Class object?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.   string is an alias for String.

Same as:

```
int ==> Int32
double ==> Double
```

and others.

Comment: strictly speaking, `System.String`, which isn't *quite* the same (depending on the context, active directives, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences. string is just an alias for System.string:

> The string data type is an alias for the System.String class.

[.NET Book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/) page 57