# Why String.ToString()?

Tags: .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: why does the string type have a .ToString() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778827/c-why-does-the-string-type-have-a-tostring-method)

Why is there a `ToString` method exist in `String` class (VB.NET)?

```
String.ToString()
```

Will it be a overhead if it is used like

```
TextBox.Text.ToString()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ToString` method is found on `Object` from which `String` inherits. The implementation of `Object.ToString` is to print the typename.

```
public virtual string ToString() {
    return this.GetType().ToString();
}
```

The type  `String` overrides this method to return itself.

```
public override string ToString() {
    return this;
}
```

The code `TextBox.Text.ToString()` has an unnecessary call to `ToString`, but it is unlikely that there will be any noticable performance impact from doing so.

Answer (score 6):

*All* objects have `ToString()`, so that for any object:

- you can call `obj.ToString()` without knowing the type of `obj`
- you can call `obj.ToString()` without having to worry about the method not being there (generic logging code is a common example of where you might do this)

The overhead of calling `ToString()` on a string is only a call to a one-line function, so it's almost certain to be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

`ToString()` exists in every class derived from `System.Object`. And yes, that includes `System.String` as well.

It's perhaps a bit superfluous there and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tc6ws5s.aspx) states that it will return the exact same instance. So there is no performance overhead there except for the method call.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is an object (or can be boxed as an object). `object` defines the method `ToString`, ergo, string has a ToString method, because it's an object.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `System.String` class, like any other class is derived from the `System.Object` class,
it automatically inherits from various methods like :

```
public virtual bool Equals(Object obj)
public virtual int GetHashCode()
public virtual string ToString()
```

thus enabling you to compare, fill tables with objects, and turn objets into human-friendly strings.