# Is ToString a Static Method?

Tags: c#, static, extension-methods, tostring

I researched *extension methods* and found out they are `static`.
I want to know if `ToString` is a `static` method?

Because all *extension methods* are `static` ... so `ToString` is a *static* method too?

Comment: No - it's just a regular virtual method that's defined on the very base `Object` class ... - see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-8.0

Comment: What makes you think [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-8.0) is an _extension_ method?

Comment: @marc_s Thank u , u mean tostring is a public virtual method that C# will create in all Class ?

Comment: @Fildor I thought it was because it was used without an instance

Comment: _"because it was used without an instance"_ - do you have an example of that? Of course, someone could have created a static method or extension method of the same name and signature. But the plain old standard "ToString" that comes with the "original package" is just a virtual instance method.

Comment: @YaSecu everything in C# is an object. The base object class is named "Object" and every other object / class INHERITS from that class Object. Even if you don`t explicitly inherit the compiler will do that for you.

Comment: _"everything in C# is an object"_ ... weeeeelllll ... ;D let's say _at least_ every class.

Comment: Thank U guys :) At least I understood The more I get to know C#, the more I get away from it

Comment: @Fildor "at least every class" `static class Mwahaahah {}` is a class, no objects ;

Comment: Da*@!t, Marc! :D OK, not even that was correct. But that kind of proves the point I was trying to make ... (would "every non-static class" have been enough?)

Comment: _"The more I get to know C#, the more I get away from it"_ - what? why? (Just curious) Do you already know a different language and get frustrated or is it your "first"?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2778833/3744182) by Mark Byers to [Why does the string type have a .ToString() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2778827/3744182), which states *The type `System.String`, like almost all types in .NET, derives from `System.Object`. Object has a ToString() method and so String inherits this method*, answer your question?

Comment: @Fildor yes its my first , but im not new ... I have been writing Webaplication for at least a year (ASP.Net Core) ... and now I understand that .tostring is not extension method XD

Comment: Yeah that's still fairly new. Keep it up, it will get easier :)

Comment: @dbc  Finally... your answer + the link you posted + the correction of other friends about my wrong is The finally answer

Answer (score 1):

In C#, ToString is an instance method, not a static method.

for example:

```
int num = 715;
string str = num.ToString();
```

`num` is an `int` type and `ToString` is called on an instance of the number.
`ToString` is defined in `System.Object`

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect methods (`ToString()` in your case) with a help of *reflection*:

```
using System.Reflection;

... 

// We want to get information about ToString method of object class
// Let's try public and no public methods either instance or static
var methodInfo = typeof(object).GetMethod(
  "ToString",
   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | 
   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

if (methodInfo is null)
    Console.WriteLine("Method is not found");
else
    Console.WriteLine(methodInfo.IsStatic ? "Static" : "Instance");
```

Output:

```
Instance
```

So we can conclude, that `ToString` is a typical *instance* method of `Object` class.

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nWw7td) yourself.