# What is the difference Between String and string?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

What is the difference Between String and string or Double and double?

if i use :

double s1; or

if i use Double s1;

can you give pros and cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` is an alias for `System.String`. It doesn't matter whether you use `String` or `string`. It's in the end translated into `System.String` anyway.

It's the same case as with `System.Int32` and `int` etc.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the list of all aliases.

Answer (score 11):

string is just the C# alias for the [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) class. The same is true for all the other built-in language types like:

- int (System.Int32)
- float (System.Single)
- double (System.Double)
- decimal (System.Decimal)
- bool (System.Boolean)
- and so on...

As far as usage conventions go, I completely agree with [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string/7077#7077).

Related resources:

- [C# Built-in Types Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: And `double` is an alias for `System.Double`.

Answer (score 2):

See : [string (Référence C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/362314fe(v=VS.80).aspx)

According to MSDN :

> The string type represents a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters. string is an alias for String in the .NET Framework.

In short, no difference, as one is a sugar syntax for the other.

Comment: you linked to the French language version of MSDN :P

Comment: Thanks for mentionning it! =) I changed the link for the English one.

Answer (score 2):

string or String is CLR aliases for System.String