# C# in VS2005: what is the best way to check if a string is empty?

Tags: c#, string

What is the best way to check if a string is empty in C# in VS2005?

Comment: Fantastic. 5 nearly identical answers within minutes of the posting of what is arguably the simplest C# question in SO history. Covered in meta; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/noob-questions-simple-answers-and-big-rep-points

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's the builtin `String.IsNullOrEmpty` which I'd use. It's described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx).

Comment: +1 for `String` instead of `string`. Similarly to `Int32.TryParse` instead of `int.TryParse`

Comment: @abatishchev: Note that there is no semantical difference between those two. Jon Skeet explained quite well when it makes sense to use each of the variants: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c/215422#215422. In fact, the C# spec states: "As a matter of style, use of the keyword is favored over use of the complete system type name."

Comment: @0xA3: Undoubtedly. For me, first of all, this is just style of code

Answer (score 6):

try this one:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(YourStringVariable))
{
    //TO Do
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above you can use String.IsNullOrEmpty, but that will not work if you also want to check for strings with only spaces (some users place a space when a field is required). In that case you can use:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || str.Trim().Length == 0) {
  // String was empty or whitespaced
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# 4 has the [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method which will handle cases where your string is made up of whitespace ony.

Comment: ... which doesn't matter since it was asked for VS2005, i.e. .NET 2.0. Would have been a great comment though.

Answer (score 0):

The `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` method on the string class itself.

You could use

```
string.Length == 0
```

but that will except if the string is null.

Answer (score 0):

ofc

```
bool isStringEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty("yourString");
```