# What is the difference between "string" and "String"?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between these two declarations?

```
string str;
String str;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String vs string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In normal usage, `string` and `String` are identical; `string` is simply an alias for `global::System.String`. There *are* some edge-cases, though:

- you need a `using System;` to use `String` - you don't for `string`
- if you define a local `class String {}`, then `String` refers to **that** (this would be a silly thing to do, of course). You *can't* define a class called `string` (although `@string` is fine)

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. string (lower case) is just an alias for System.String.

Comment: Yes, but `string` is *always* an alias for `System.String`, whereas `String` just follows the normal type lookup rules. If, for example, you have *another* class called `String` in the current scope, `String` will refer to *that*, and not to `System.String`.

Answer (score 2):

string is a c# keyword.
String is the System.String .NET type.

The C# compiler provided by MS maps the string keyword to the System.String .NET type, so they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing really, in C# the type keywords actually are synonyms for the types. So int = System.Int32 short = System.Int16 and string = System.String.

Answer (score 1):

String is an alias for System.String object, so none.

System.String is a Common Type System type necessary for interaction with other .NET languages. "string" is just C# shortcut to this name (in the same way int is shortcut to System.Int32)

Answer (score -1):

They are the same, no difference, string is simply an alias for the System.String type, there are other similar cases in C#, like int and System.Int32, long and System.Int64 (see another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care))

Curiously though, whilst you can use alias in your code in place of the fully qualified types, you still need to know the underlying type when you use the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bds4fye2.aspx) class because there's no ToInt or ToLong methods but only ToInt32 and ToInt64..

Comment: Not as curious as it sounds: `Convert` is a framework class, not a language keyword.  If it had methods named after the C# keywords, the methods would make no sense in VB or F# or other .NET languages.