# what is difference between System.String and System.string in c#.net?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

What is difference between `System.String` and `System.string` in *C# .NET* ?
Can i compare variable of `System.String` with `System.string` ?

Comment: They are the same, string in an alias of System.String. Duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c Many good answers there.

Comment: `System.string` won't compile. It's either `string` or `System.String`

Answer (score 2):

`string` is an alias of `String`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) (string (C# Reference)):

> string is an alias for String in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

string is a shorthand to System.String, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes, nothing! `String` is just an alias for `string`.