# Why am I getting an exception with the following code?

Tags: c#, viewmodel

I have a property defined in an interface as:

```
 Boolean IsBusy { get; }
```

It is implemented in the class as:

```
private Boolean _isBusy = false;
public Boolean IsBusy
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isBusy;
        }

        private set
        {
            if (this._isBusy != value)
            {
                this._isBusy = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then when I run the app, I always get following kind of error when check IsBusy value in constructor:

'IsBusy' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' bool {System.NullReferenceException}

I can't figure it out. If I change all `Boolean` to `bool`, get same error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you privide fragment of your constructor, where you call IsBusy?

Answer (score 10):

You fix it by checking whether `OnPropertyChanged` is null before calling it, assuming `OnPropertyChanged` is an event or a delegate variable (you haven't made this clear). This has nothing to do with `bool` or `Boolean`, which are equivalent (assuming that `Boolean` is resolved to `System.Boolean`).

I can't see any other reason it would throw `NullReferenceException` - although it would really help you could clarify whether you were calling the getter or the setter at the time it threw the exception. A short but complete example would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`bool` is just a syntax shortcut for `Boolean`

Answer (score 1):

Both `bool` and `Boolean` evaluate to the same thing in compilation.

Answer (score 1):

none. `Boolean` is what the .net CLI uses to represent a true/false value. `bool` is what c# uses.

Answer (score 1):

1. `bool` is a C# alias for the struct `System.Boolean`. They are the same.
2. Your problem probably is that `this.OnPropertyChanged` is unassigned. This is completely unrelated to `bool` vs `Boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

C# contains aliase for all the native types. String for string, Int32 for int, etc. there is no difference with which you use:

[String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

Boolean cannot be NULL, so you are likely getting an error because of something in OnPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

The `bool` keyword is just a type alias for the `Boolean` keyword.

Just the same as `int` is an alias for `Int32`.