# String or string

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

what's the difference between the String and string. In C#, which is preferred?

Comment: @Ani: Not "possibly," but "definitely."

Comment: @Jason: That's the boilerplate text that turns up when I choose "close as exact duplicate." Can I change that?

Comment: @Ani: I was not aware that there is such a feature. Is that new?

Comment: @Jason: No idea. Maybe it works differently for users with different rep?

Answer (score 5):

Actually `string` is an alias for `System.String` but erash is basically right...

Here is a list of other alias' shamelessly lifted from Jon Skeet in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c):

```
* object: System.Object
* string: System.String
* bool: System.Boolean
* byte: System.Byte
* sbyte: System.SByte
* short: System.Int16
* ushort: System.UInt16
* int: System.Int32
* uint: System.UInt32
* long: System.Int64
* ulong: System.UInt64
* float: System.Single
* double: System.Double
* decimal: System.Decimal
* char: System.Char
```

Answer (score 2):

They are the same this, string is an alias for String.

I tend to use String when calling static methods (i.e., String.Format(...) or String.IsNullOrEmpty(...).  I don't know why, I just do.

Comment: I do the same, probably because it feels wrong calling a static method on something that doesn't look like a class.

Comment: Haha, yeah, maybe that's it.  I prefer teal to blue.

Comment: It makes sense... when you're using it like a class, you want it to look like a class.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is just an alias for `String` -- they are the same

edit: type fixed

Comment: I think you actually have that backwards.

Comment: I think it's the other way around. Like `int` is an alias for `Int32`

Answer (score 1):

`string` is a C#-specific keyword that means the same thing as the `System.String` type.  Prefer the language keywords where possible, so use e.g. `string`, `int`, `float`, instead of `System.String`, `System.Int32`, `System.Single`.

Comment: Aside from the fact that it looks a *lot* cleaner, this is the guideline in most open source projects and is the style MS uses in their documentation.

Comment: float == Single? Didn't know that... I guess it's half a double though so that makes sense... still a funny name though.

Comment: For the rest I would agree about the 'it looks cleaner' statement, but the question is about the String class, and I don't think string looks any cleaner than String.  In general though, yeah.

Comment: If he was not asking about the class, what else would he be asking about?  When you reference the class from code when e.g. declaring a variable, do you not use `string`?