# Difference b/w String and string

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

Hi,

Can anyone tell me the difference between the two lines of code below:

```
public const String sample = "Sample";
public const string sample2 = "Sample2";
```

Both "String" and "string" are of System.String.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same as [In C# what is the difference between String and string
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string).

Answer (score 1):

These data types are exactly the same, as string is just an alias for the class String. If you have a look, there are similar capitalized and non capitalized versions of int, float and similar classes.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string) for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are the same

string is an alias in the C# for .Net System.String, like int is for Int32, long is for int64 and etc. C# string replaced by System.String during compilation

Answer (score 0):

No difference what so ever - in fact you can write the following code:

```
String sample = "Sample";
string sample2 = sample;
```

Both maps to the same IL string type

Answer (score 0):

[String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c/215304#215304)

> String stands for System.String and it is a .NET Framework type. string is an alias in the C# language for System.String. Both of them are compiled to System.String in IL (Intermediate Language), so there is no difference. Choose what you like and use that. If you code in C#, I'd prefer string as it's a C# type alias and well-know by C# programmers.

Answer (score 0):

String is CTS type but string is c# string object.

You can use String to any of dot net language.

Answer (score 0):

both are the same
string -> c# type which gets converted to
String -> .net type

Answer (score 0):

String is the .NET class for the CLR built-in string type.  string is the C# language identifier that maps to the CLR String type.  They are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

"string" is actually an alias for System.String. They're the same.

Try:

```
typeof(string) == typeof(String) == typeof(System.String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really, in C# the type keywords actually are synonyms for the types. So int = System.Int32 short = System.Int16 and string = System.String.

They have the keywords because they are easier to remember and programmers coming from other languages like c/c++ would also be familiar with these types.

Anyway, look at the C# keyword reference and you can find these things out. This was taken from the string keyword reference.

The string type represents a string of Unicode characters. string is an alias for String in the .NET Framework. Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created.