# string or String, int or Int32, byte or Byte? Which you prefer and why?

Tags: .net, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

Yeah, I knew that both of 2 style is ok, but which one is better, and why?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, it is subject to opinion.

The less disputable facts:

- Always use whichever your team already uses, or whichever your coding standard mandates
- In favor of the keyword style, it doesn't require a `using` declaration.
- In output from a code generator, using the fully qualified name is less of a pain to code; otherwise you have to include special handling for keyword types
- In naming properties or methods, you should use the type name, not the keyword name.  It must be translatable across .Net languages

If it is a new project, and you are in control of the coding style, use whichever tickles your fancy.

In addition to the method/property naming requirement, I've seen people say they prefer the non-keyword type name, so that it is more directly grokable across .Net languages.  My opinion on this opinion is to write code to the language you are in.

Answer (score 0):

read this thread [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c) which is about String and string

Answer (score 0):

The similar question was raised previously in StackOverFlow. And the Answer to it is given. Please refer to the following link for details:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I'll add that StyleCop ( http://stylecop.codeplex.com/ ) "prefers" the "lower case" versions.

```
SA1121 Readability Rules UseBuiltInTypeAlias
```

> A violation of this rule occurs when
>   one of the following types are used
>   anywhere in the code: Array, Boolean,
>   Byte, Char, Decimal, Double, Int16,
>   Int32, Int64, Object, SByte, Single,
>   String, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64.
>
> A violation also occurs when any of
>   these types are represented in the
>   code using the full namespace for the
>   type: System.Array, System.Boolean,
>   System.Byte, System.Char,
>   System.Decimal, System.Double,
>   System.Int16, System.Int32,
>   System.Int64, System.Object,
>   System.SByte, System.Single,
>   System.String, System.UInt16,
>   System.UInt32, System.UInt64.
>
> Rather than using the type name or the
>   fully-qualified type name, the
>   built-in aliases for these types
>   should always be used: array, bool,
>   byte, char, decimal, double, short,
>   int, long, object, sbyte, single,
>   string, ushort, uint, ulong.

(taken from the help file StyleCop.chm)