# Should I prefer string or String in C# or is it execlty the same?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

Hello,

Should I prefer string or String in C# or is it execlty the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is an alias of `String`..

Both create same IL

Demonstration

```
string sTest;
```

IL Creates

```
IL_0000:  ret
```

---

```
String sTest;
```

IL Creates

```
IL_0000:  ret
```

Its already asked so many times

Answer (score 0):

`string` is an alias `System.String`, they are the same. However, I would advise you to choose one and stick with it, so other people have an easier read.