# why two keywords in c#: String and string

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

I see there are 2 different keywords (classes ?) one which starts with capital S and other with small in c#.

String and string

What is the reason ? is one not sufficient ?

Comment: 11 years later and still looking for the WHY part of this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` is a keyword and alias of `System.String` class, `System.String` is a class. Also there's more aliases than `string`:

```
object: System.Object
string: System.String
bool: System.Boolean
byte: System.Byte
sbyte: System.SByte
short: System.Int16
ushort: System.UInt16
int: System.Int32
uint: System.UInt32
long: System.Int64
ulong: System.UInt64
float: System.Single
double: System.Double
decimal: System.Decimal
char: System.Char
```

The best answer comes from Jeffrey Richter in his book CLR Via C#. Here are his 3 reasons:

> - I've seen a number of developers confused, not knowing whether to
>     use    string or String in their code. Because in C# the string (a
>     keyword)    maps exactly to System.String (an FCL type), there is no
>     difference    and either can be used.
> - In C#, long maps to System.Int64, but in a different programming
>     language, long could map to an Int16 or Int32. In fact, C++/CLI does
>     in fact treat long as an Int32. Someone reading source code in one
>     language could easily misinterpret the code's intention if he or she
>     were used to programming in a different programming language. In fact,
>     most languages won't even treat long as a keyword and won't compile
>     code that uses it.
> - The FCL has many methods that have type names as part of their
>     method    names. For example, the BinaryReader type offers methods
>     such as    ReadBoolean, ReadInt32, ReadSingle, and so on, and the
>     System.Convert    type offers methods such as ToBoolean, ToInt32,
>     ToSingle, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

`string` is a C# language alias for the actual class `System.String`.

You can safely use either. I've seen most people prefer `string`. If I'm working on an API I'll typically use `System.String` instead although both are safe.

There's plenty of other aliases, too. For example `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`, `bool` for `System.Boolean`. The string example just happens to be a casing difference so this question comes up a lot.

Comment: Same as int/Int32, bool/Boolean, double/Double etc.  Many common types are aliased to more familiar (C/C++) keywords.

Comment: @Antony Scott: Like BoltClock said, there aren't two. One is just an alias. `string` just refers to the `String` class definition in the BCL.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is only one keyword for string (all C# keywords are lowercase).  They mean the same thing.  They are only interchangeable, though, if you have a `using System;` import.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is the actual class you are using. It is just another class, nothing more. However, since strings are so vital in programming, Microsoft decided to bake them into the language by creating a keyword `string` that was just an alias for `System.String`. There is no such thing as an instance of `string` because it is not a class.

This gave strings elevated status and made them a lot easier to find (imagine trying to write a hello world style programming and have to actually look around and find the String class...) :D