# Equivalence of String and string in C# test

Tags: c#, string, class, autoboxing, type-equivalence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

I have a test in C# code I'm reading:

```
if (variable is string)
```

I am wondering if this is strictly equivalent to:

```
if (variable is String)
```

or if some esoteric behavior of C# autoboxing may cause these tests to behave differently.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c

Comment: There's no boxing here. Boxing only applies to value types, and `System.String` (and thus its alias `string`) is a reference type.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I did not search hard enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are exactly the same - `string` is an alias for `System.String`.