# string variable declaration

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

I am using .Net Framework 4.0

I have a query for syntax. I can declare the string variable in two ways like below.

```
1. String str = null;
2. string str = null;
```

Somebody suggested me to go for first one. Is it the reason like looking good or any differences also ?

Comment: See this previous post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` is an alias for `System.String` (which is what your first line uses). They compile the same.

The only reason to go with one over the other is convention. Pick one and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

there is absolutly no difference : right click on the "string" on the second one and do "go to definition" and you'll end up on the definition of the first one.

My guess is they created the 2nd one for the older developer who use to use this syntax.

Comment: sorry I'm not part of the .net team, so all I can do is ... guess, I tried to mail "developer@microsoft.net" but couldn't and here the reason is not the question so I'm just saying in the hope that someone will come with a great explanation or maybe an other wiser guess

Comment: No need to hope. There are lots of good answers.

Comment: @David , I don't understand. Which answer explains why there is these aliases ?

Comment: that wasn't the question

Comment: @David ok ... still don't get your point. I added it to open the question and try to go further but it seems like a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is the name of the .NET Framework class (`System.String`). This name is the same over all languages targeting the .NET Framework (which is the reason why I prefer this syntax). `string` is basically a C# specific alias.

Same for `Object` and `object`.