# the internals of System.String

Tags: c#, string, reflection

I used reflection to look at the internal fields of System.String and I found three fields:

```
m_arrayLength

m_stringLength

m_firstChar
```

I don't understand how this works.

m_arrayLength is the length of some array.  Where is this array?  It's apparently not a member field of the string class.

m_stringLength makes sense.  It's the length of the string.

m_firstChar is the first character in the string.

So my question is where are the rest of the characters for the string?  Where are the contents of the string stored if not in the string class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Much of the implementation of `System.String` is in native code (C/C++) and not in managed code (C#). If you take a look at the decompiled code you'll see that most of the "interesting" or "core" methods are decorated with this attribute:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
```

Only some of the helper/convenience APIs are implemented in C#.

So where are the characters for the string stored? It's top secret! Deep down inside the CLR's core native code implementation.

Answer (score 14):

The first char provides access (via `&m_firstChar`) to an address in memory of the first character in the buffer. The length tells it how many characters are in the `string`, making `.Length` efficient (better than looking for a `nul` char). Note that strings can be oversized (especially if created with `StringBuilder`, and a few other scenarios), so sometimes the actual buffer is actually longer than the string. So it is important to track this. StringBuilder, for example, actually *mutates* a string within its buffer, so it needs to know how much it can add before having to create a larger buffer (see `AppendInPlace`, for example).

Comment: @Marc, I think your description (just the first bit) is a little confusing. If `m_firstChar` is a `char`, then it's address cannot be the location of a string. If instead it's an address of the first char in an array of `char`s), it doesn't make sense to use `&m_firstChar` which would give you the address of the pointer, no? Unless C# is wildly different to its brethren which is a possibility - I don't know a great deal about it.

Comment: @paxdiablo if you look at the decompiled code you'll see that the first char is the actual first char of the in-memory string. Thus, getting its address and indexing past that initial memory address will be the rest of the characters.

Comment: So m_firstChar is actually the array (which would degrade to a pointer in C)?

Comment: @paxdiablo I deliberately used the word "buffer", not string or array - as it is neither ;-p `string` is one of the two types in .NET (*along* with arrays) with indeterminate size. The buffer starts at the address of field m_firstChar. You could say that string is implemented *similarly* to an array, rather than *encapsulating* an array (which it doesn't; there *is* no `char[]` here).

Answer (score 2):

I'd be thinking immediately that `m_firstChar` is *not* the first character, rather a pointer to the first character. That would make much more sense (although, since I'm not privy to the source, I can't be certain).

It makes little sense to store the first character of a string unless you want a blindingly fast `s.substring(0,1)` operation :-) There's a good chance the characters themselves (that the three fields allude to) will be allocated separately from the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer on difference between string and System.string is here: [string vs System.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

There is nothing about native implementations