# Management of strings in structs

Tags: c#, string, struct

I know that strings have variable length, therefore they need variable space in memory to be stored. When we define a string item in a `struct`, the `struct`'s size would then be variable in length.

Older languages managed this by using fixed-length strings.  However, there is no way to define fixed-length strings in C#, and C# manages normal strings in `struct`s pretty good.

This becomes more weird when we define an array of such `struct`s, or simply an array of strings. As result of any change (decrease/increase) in length of one string, all forward `struct`s must be shifted.

How does C# handle variable-length strings in structs?

Comment: C# is not C - you are assuming that memory is managed the same way in both.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The string itself is not stored in the struct. Instead a reference to the string is stored in the struct, so the struct size never changes.

`string` is not a value type; .NET strings are *interned*, which means that each unique string is stored in a look-up table in memory.

Comment: Did you mean "Is a value type"?

Comment: No, a string is not a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

Comment: But the reference to the string is a value type? Correct? So a struct copies the ref(memory address) of the string on the heap. Your answer needs to be fixed.

Comment: I'm not a C# language lawyer, but AFAIK, a C# reference itself doesn't have a type. You're correct that a reference behaves like a value type (e.g., you can't pass a reference to a reference the way you can pass a pointer to a pointer in C), but in my answer, "which is not a value type" is intended to modify "string" rather than "a reference [to the string]". I can understand how one might read it as the latter, but I think most people would read it as the former. In any case, now there's a long clarification in the comments.

Comment: Read this as "reference (which is not a value type) to the string". Could definitely use a slight cleanup IMO

Comment: @jjlin Not all strings are interned as far as I remember: literal strings are interned by default, strings where `String.Intern()` is called are interned, but all the other are regular managed objects that can be garbage-collected I reckon. Also, in .NET it's safe to say that, no matter what, strings reside in the heap, so yup in a struct you'll have the reference to that heap location ;-)

Answer (score 15):

My first question to you would be, do your requirements dictate that a fixed length string is needed?  If so a char[] might actually be what you are intending to use.

The .NET framework does not use C-style strings (char arrays) directly,  but instead represents strings by immutable references.  When a string is appended to or modified, you are actually creating a new string object in memory.  This is a desired feature of the platform but one that requires consideration as expecting magically resizing strings can lead to some undesired side-effects.

Back to your question.  "How does C# manage strings in structs?"

One of two ways to interpret this question from what I see:

1).  How can I create structs that contain strings, and how does the .NET Framework manage strings in this scenario?

Short answer: keep in mind that strings are immutable types.  Create your struct normally, and realize that the struct only contains a reference to the string, not a magically resizing segment of the struct that expands to include your volatile string.

2).  How can the .NET Framework resize strings if they are a value type represented by structs.

Short answer, it doesn't.  This isn't how .NET works with strings, see above.

Comment: Thank you Firoso. No, I'm happy with strings. I was just concerned about the great time complexity of operations over structs and arrays of strings. Now I know the trick: "reference to the string".

Comment: If you are concerned about the efficiency of strong manipulation and mutation, consider using the StringBuilder class.

Answer (score 9):

+1 to jjlin for a concise and accurate answer to the question, but a more general answer may be useful:

A field or variable declaration *of any reference type* represents a storage location *for the reference.*  This is also true for fields of a struct.

(Including reference-type fields in a struct makes that type a "managed type", which is important in unsafe code; you can't declare a pointer to a managed type.)

Answer (score 4):

C# manages strings in structs the way it manages strings in general. See:

- [the internals of System.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107375/the-internals-of-system-string)

Answer (score -7):

Structure save in stack and string stores on heap.

Same as primitive types saves on stack and reference types saves on heap.