# How a Struct with string type member field is value type?

Tags: c#, class, struct

We all know Struct is *value* type. If we see below struct it contains 2 field members one *integer* and another is *string*. We also know *string* is *reference* type. So, how following struct is value type?

```
    struct Student  
    { 
        public int Roll_no;  
        public string Name;  
    }                                                                             
    Student student = new Student();
    student.Roll_no = 1;
    student.Name = "Manas";
```

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334231/194717

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? It's a pair of two *values* ‒ one integer and one object reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why reference types inside structs behave like value types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564712/why-reference-types-inside-structs-behave-like-value-types)

Answer (score 0):

The object of this structure will have an integer on the stack and a string reference, which point to place in heap, where placed value of this string, but i need to mention, struct can stored in heap in some [cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853213/are-structs-always-stack-allocated-or-sometimes-heap-allocated)

Comment: _"The object of this structure will have an integer on the stack"_ - not quite: a value-type or `struct` member of a `class` (such as `Int32`) won't live on the stack (until it's an operand), for example.

Comment: @Dai, yep, forget to mention, thanks