# In C# what is the difference: string vs String

Tags: c#, .net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

In C# there is `string` and there is `System.String`.

What is the difference between these?  Is one considered better to use that the other.  Are there any hidden dangers in mixing the use of them?

If they are the same, then why have them both?  Why not just have one or the other?

Comment: This is a duplicate many times over. Please see http://www.google.com/search?q=difference+string+vs+string+site%3AStackoverflow.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I did not realize it was such a duplicate.  Sorry for not searching better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.String` is the name of the actual .NET CLR class, just like `System.Int32` is the real name of that class.  But the designers of C# wanted it to look a lot like C and C++, where the native types (like `int`) are in lower case, so they added aliases for the basic native types.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

*The string type represents a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters. string is an alias for String in the .NET Framework.*

Answer (score 4):

No difference string is an alias for String.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

For more information, see the following sections in the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

2.4.2 Identifiers

2.4.4.5 String literals

4.2.3 The string type

7.9.7 String equality operators

Answer (score 3):

string is just an alias for System.String