# Difference between byte vs Byte data types in C#

Tags: c#, byte

I noticed that in C# there are both a **byte** and **Byte** data type. They both say they are of type **struct System.Byte** and represent an 8-digit unsigned integer.

What are the differences (if any) between the two, and why you would use one over the other?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The `byte` keyword is an alias for the `System.Byte` data type.

They represent the same data type, so the resulting code is identical. There are only some differences in usage:

- You can use `byte` even if the `System` namespace is not included. To use `Byte` you have to have a `using System;` at the top of the page, or specify the full namespace `System.Byte`.
- There are a few situations where C# only allows you to use the keyword, not the framework type, for example:

.

```
enum Fruits : byte // this works
{
  Apple, Orange
}

enum Fruits : Byte // this doesn't work
{
  Apple, Orange
}
```

For detailed other alias, please follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215422/7171758).

Comment: @RadhaManohar byte[] / Byte[]. Two names for the same thing. Even the MSDN documentation switches between them; check out [Encoding.GetBytes MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8) (which, at the time of this comment, has byte[] as the return type in the method signature, and Byte[] as the return type in the documentation)

Answer (score 26):

`byte` and `System.Byte` in C# are identical. `byte` is simply syntactic sugar, and is recommended by StyleCop (for style guidelines).

Answer (score 8):

No difference. `byte` is alias to System.Byte, the same way `int` is alias to System.Int32, `long` to System.Int64, `string` to System.String, ...

Answer (score 6):

C# has a number of aliases for the .NET types. `byte` is an alias for `Byte` just as `string` is an alias for `String` and `int` is an alias for `Int32`. I.e. `byte` and `Byte` are the same actual type.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing, the lowercase one is a keyword which is an alias for the Byte type.

This is pure syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 4):

They are generally the same.

Answer (score 1):

`byte` is a built-in data type in C#.
`System.Byte` is a struct that represent a `byte` and provides extra methods like `Parse` and `TryParse`.

`byte` is alias of `System.Byte` struct. Different .NET languages have different aliases based on the semantics of the particular language, but they all map to specific types in the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

also when using reflection ,,,

```
Type t=Type.GetType("System.Byte"); //works

Type t=Type.GetType("System.byte"); //doesn't work, I can see no way to use"byte" directly here without converting it to "Byte"
```

Comment: There is no "converting it to Byte" concept.  **byte** and `System.Byte` are 100% identical.  There is no difference whatsoever.  This is unlike Java where they are actually discrete classes.