# What is the difference between char and Char?

Tags: c#, .net, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

When I run:

```
char c1 = 'a';
Console.WriteLine(c1);
```

and when I run:

```
Char c2 = 'a';
Console.WriteLine(c2);
```

I get exactly the same result, `a`.

I wanted to know what is the difference between the two forms, and why are there two forms?

Comment: Such questions can be self-answered. From your point above just go ahead with 'if(c1.GetType() == c2.GetType()){ MessageBox.Show("Same"!); }. Compare the getType()-output of both variables. The system will tell you the answer. ^^

Answer (score 14):

The result is exactly the same. Both represent the same type, so the resulting executables are completely identical.

The `char` keyword is an alias in the C# language for the type `System.Char` in the framework.

You can always use the `char` keyword. To use `Char` you need a `using System;` at the top of the file to include the `System` namespace (or use `System.Char` to specify the namespace).

---

In most situations you can use either a keyword or the framework type, but not everywhere. For example as backing type in an enum, you can only use the keyword:

```
enum Test : int { } // works

enum Test : Int32 {} // doesn't work
```

(I use `int` in the example, as You can't use a `char` as backing type for an enum.)

---

Related: [Difference between byte vs Byte data types in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415742/difference-between-byte-vs-byte-data-types-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, C# `char` type keyword is simply an alias for `System.Char`, so they refer to the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `char` is an alias of the `System.Char` type in C#.