# What is the difference between the type String and type string? (Uppercase first letter)

Tags: c#, .net, clr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

I couldn't find the info anywhere, but I'm sure it's just a simple answer. Are they interchangeable??

Comment: This question turns up on SO soooo often. And it's always, always String, even with all the numeric types, it's always String. I wonder why.

Comment: @RichK: my guess is that people probably see `string` and `String` somewhat frequently in code while `Int32` and `Int64` are rarer (`Boolean` even more so).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are identical.  `string` is just the C# name for a `System.String`, which you can also use.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> The string type represents a string of Unicode characters. string is an alias for System.String in the .NET Framework.

It's personal preference, but I always use `string` over `String`.  I guess I like the blue color over the, uh, turquoise color offered by the default syntax highlighting.

You can see the other aliases under the [C# value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) on MSDN (e.g. `int` is really `System.Int32` while `long` is really `System.Int64`).

Answer (score -1):

You get this question a lot because in java there is a difference between for example Integer and int (pointer allocation). In C# there is no difference between String and string, nor there is a difference between Int32 and int etc..

Comment: This is wrong, as has been discussed countless times already here on StackOverflow. `string` is an alias for `System.String`, i.e. it will *always* be the framework class. `String` follows the normal lookup rules, i.e. it will use *any* class named `String` which happens to be in scope.

Comment: euhm.. this isn't wrong ?? any good programmer would not create their own String class (and if they must they would name it MyString or something)..And I just pointed out that in JAVA there is a difference between a primitive (int) and an object (Integer).